# Algorithm to find flight connectivity for 500,000 flights

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, sql-server-2008, graph

There are around 500,000 records for which I want to find the Onward flight for the previous Flight. An example is such:

```
Flight 1    Rodez - Beziers
Flight 2    Beziers - Biarritz
Flight 3    Biarritz - Rodez 
Flight 4    Blois - Montauban
```

Now from above we can find that the onward of `Flight 1` is `Flight 2`. Similarly onward of `Flight 2` is `Flight 3` and `Flight 4` has no onward neither is it itself an onward of any.

I could do this in C# using Graphs, but I do not know how will I handle so much data (500,000 records). Or if I do this in SQL, how do I go about it? Note I do not want a complete implementation I just want to know:

> 1. First - whether I should do this in C# or SQL since Performance is a concern.
> 2. Second - how to implement this algorithm in SQL without any data structure like Graph.

Comment: Your sample data leads to an infinite loop between flights 1, 2 and 3. Please provide more accurate sample data. knowing the correct table structure may be the difference between a great answer and a terrible one.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what you have here is ORIGIN and DEST(INATION).

I would start with getting a list of all ORIGINs that do not appear in the DEST column. These are not onward flights, so lets call them STARTP(OINTS).

SQL solution:

For each one of the STARTP, set it as an anchor and then run a recursive statement that will concatenate the onward flights (looking for the previous DEST value in any ORIGIN record).

Answer (score 0):

**whether i should do this in C# or SQL since Performance is a concern**

SQL is faster than code processing since it is only logical access to static data. You should definitively modelize your problem in SQL.
Which means, you should also use [stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx) to quickly perform recurring query.

**how to implement this algo in SQL without any data structure like Graph**

If you don't have a database yet, create one which will modelize your problem. For example, if I were you I would have one single table :

```
              ***** FLIGHT *****

FLIGHT_Id    FLIGHT_cityBegin    FLIGHT_cityEnd

1            Rodez               Beziers
2            Beziers             Biarritz
```

And stored procedure to know the onwards flight would looks like :

```
USE [your_database_name]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE your_procedure_name 
        @sql_flight_id    int
AS

DECLARE @sql_return       int
        SELECT            @sql_return = FLIGHT_Id
        FROM              [dbo].[FLIGHT]
        WHERE             FLIGHT_cityEnd = (SELECT  FLIGHT_cityBegin
                                            FROM    [dbo].[FLIGHT]
                                            WHERE   FLIGHT_Id = @sql_flight_id)
RETURN 0
```

And to use this stored procedure in server side (C#) :

```
protected int getFlightOnward(int flightId) 
{
    int id_flight_onward = -1;

    string connection_string = /* get database infos */;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);

    try 
    {
        con.Open(); 
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("your_procedure_name", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sql_flight_id", flightId);
        SqlParameter return_value = com.Parameters.Add("@sql_return", SqlDbType.Int);
        return_value.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        id_flight_onward = int.Parse(com.Parameters["@sql_return"].Value.ToString());
    }
    catch 
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    return id_flight_onward;
}
```

The function above return `-1` if no flight onward have been found, else it will return the id of the flight onward.